# Can I use Typescript generics to filter keys from an object?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a filter function with working logic, but I don't know how to write its types:

```
export function filter<T>(object: T, ...keys: Array<keyof T>): ??? {
  let index = -1;
  const length = keys.length;
  const result = { ...object };

  while (++index < length) {
    const key = keys[index];
    if (key in object) delete result[key];
  }
  return result;
}

filter({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'b')  // { a: 1 }
```

Typescript still think 'b' property exists, so I'm looking for a way to specify that `keys` get removed from `T`.

I'm familiar with `Omit` (but generally pretty new to Typescript), and I think it could play a role in this, but I haven't come up with a way to make it and the `Array` meet...

Does someone see the path I'm looking for?

(btw the specific signature of `filter` isn't important, if you have an alternative implementation that's more conducive to type-safety I'm happy to hear it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to extract `keyof T` into a generic. This should work:

```
export function filter<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, ...keys: Array<K>): Omit<T, K> {
  let index = -1;
  const length = keys.length;
  const result = { ...object };

  while (++index < length) {
    const key = keys[index];
    if (key in object) delete result[key];
  }
  return result;
}
```